# complement arithmetic

Tags: computer-science

in 10's complement arithmetic if i want to do (67-80) then 20 is 10's complemented.....and (67+20 = 87) no end carry i.e. result is in 10's complement form so the result(87) is 10's complemented(becomes 13) and a -ve sign is attached so the final result of subtraction is "-13"....but if i want (67-00) then 00 is 10's complemented i.e. (67+00=67) and since no end carry has been generated then this result(67) should be 10's complemented and after attaching a -ve sign result is "-33"....that is not correct.....could you tell where I am wrong........??

Comment: Your punctuation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

no, 100 is the complement of 00. so 67+100=167. Then you substract by 100 and you get 67 again. Although in wikipedia it does it another way.

It says 99 is the complement of 00. So then is 67+99=166. Then you subsract 100 to get 66 and at the end you add the dropped 1.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Decimal_example